# Spark reduceByKey receives its own output as input for subsequent calls

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm writing a PySpark application that computes pairwise distances between n-dimensional points in Cartesian space. I have a `flatMap` step that reads a single point and computes the various "blocks" in the pairwise similarity matrix for this point to reside (a slightly more efficient way than naive O(n^2) computations, I suppose; if you're curious, see [Section 5.2 in this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1851595) for my inspiration)

The text file containing the data points has the following format:

```
x1_1,x1_2,x1_3,...,x1_n
x2_1,x2_2,x2_3,...,x2_n
...
xm_1,xm_2,xm_3,...,xm_n
```

Here's my driver:

```
rawdata = np.loadtxt(args['input'], dtype = np.str, delimiter = "\n")
indexed = np.vstack([np.arange(rawdata.shape[0]), rawdata]).T
D = sc.parallelize(indexed)

# Broadcast variables.
BLOCKING_FACTOR = sc.broadcast(sc.defaultParallelism)
SIZE = sc.broadcast(rawdata.shape[0])

retval = D.flatMap(parse_line).reduceByKey(pairwise_blocks).collect()
```

It reads the entire text file into memory, then indexes each line, and finally runs the indexed data through a `flatMap`. Here's the `parse_line` method:

```
def parse_line(line):
    index, data = line
    index = int(index)

    v = SIZE.value
    h = BLOCKING_FACTOR.value

    edgelength = int(numpy.ceil(v / h))

    J = int(index / edgelength)
    rows = [((((I + 1) * I) / 2) + J, [0, index, data]) for I in range(0, J)]

    I = int(index / edgelength)
    cols = [((((I + 1) * I) / 2) + J, [1, index, data]) for J in range(I, h)]

    return rows + cols
```

The (k, v) pairs take the form where each key is an integer--a unique block in the final n-by-n pairwise similarity matrix--and the value is a 3-element list consisting of two integers and a string.

Here's the problem: when `reduceByKey` invokes the `pairwise_blocks` method, the output of early iterations are fed back as input to subsequent calls. To wit:

```
def pairwise_blocks(x1, x2):
    print x1 # for debugging; see below comments
    x = np.array(map(float, x1[2].split(",")))
    y = np.array(map(float, x2[2].split(",")))
    return [-1, la.norm(x - y)]
```

The first few calls return `[-1, dist]` as expected, but soon enough I get the following exception (the first two lines are the results of the debugging output in the above method):

```
[1, 1, '-8.366703221982483285e+00,-3.082631504065840300e+00']
[-1, 6.4988099869742415]
PySpark worker failed with exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/Spark/spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 77, in main
        serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
    File "/home/Spark/spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 283, in func
        def func(s, iterator): return f(iterator)
    File "/home/Spark/spark-1.0.1-bin-hadoop2/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1134, in _mergeCombiners
        combiners[k] = mergeCombiners(combiners[k], v)
    File "/home/Programming/PySpark-Affinities/cartesian.py", line 60, in pairwise_blocks
        x = np.array(map(float, x1[2].split(",")))
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

with the most recent printed debugging output having the form `[-1, dist]`. **Any idea why this is happening? Did I miss a configuration step somewhere or some documentation specifying this behavior?** I'm not a map-reduce wizard, but I've used it enough to not have even considered this behavior before, particularly since I'm using `reduceByKey`.

**Edit:** As a corollary and to help with debugging, is there any way in the `reduceByKey` step to access the key that the current call is reducing on?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Well it's very difficult to debug things like this in dynamically typed languages. If you where using Scala then your IDE would be able to easily red-underline where the problem is and give a helpful message.

Comment: The more abstract question is, I guess: under what conditions do the parameters in a Spark reducer take the value `None`/`null`? Intuitively I would think if there was a key with no corresponding values...but clearly that can't be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I humbly submit that this question reveals how much I am still learning Spark; this is indeed the correct behavior for reducers to exhibit. I'm still un-learning some of my Hadoop experience, where Hadoop Reducers effectively function as a one-two combined step of `groupByKey` followed by `reduceByKey` in Spark. My humblest apologies.

Comment: Not to mention I was inadvertently trying to reinvent Spark's `rdd.cartesian()` method; aggh!